# Module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime
currentDate = datetime.date.today()
print (currentDate)
print (currentDate.year)
```

this gives an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'
```

I am still learning python (1 week old)

Comment: What version of python do you use?

Comment: Your sample code is perfectly valid in both python 2 and python 3. Are you sure you executed this exact same code ?

Comment: What's the name of your main module? is it by any chance ``datetime.py``? Or is there any``datetime.py`` file in the root folder of your main module? Then you would be importing your own module instead of the built-in module.

Comment: Print `datetime.__file__` to know what module you are actually importing.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following import:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: This won't help. You are not into the problem, have you tried OP's snippet, i believe you don't since it's absolutely valid.

Answer (score -1):

I am using VSCode and Python 3.

Faced similar problem *AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'*

I had named my file as datetime.py so I guess it was importing itself.
I changed it to datetimemanipulations.py and I was able to print today's date.

[image: Changed name to datetimemanipulations.py]

```
import datetime as dt
print(dt.date.today())
```